# Remove the * symbol from a cell that is generated from importhtml in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so the formula pulls data from a stock website that produces the dividend payout.

the formula is `=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl","table",8),11,8)`

so this currently produces `18.20` inside the cell, and normally I wouldn't mind the * symbols but the reason I want them removed is that I cant number format or conditional format the color of positive or negative numbers.... because of the * symbol.

so I was wondering if there is a way to remove the symbol or still format the numbers without having to use extra cells?

Thanks a lot in advance, this is my first time using **StackOverflow**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the actual underlying number value, you'll need something like this:

`=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl","table",8),11,8),"[*]",""))`

Otherwise, your return will be a string, not a number.

Then format that cell as a percentage using **Format > Number > Percentage**. If, like the given example, all returns will include a percentage symbol (not shown in your post but retrieved when I copied and pasted your original formula into a sheet).

**ADDENDUM** (*based on user comment of 6/7/21*)

Since there may be other characters than an asterisk in the retrieved data, use this version:

`=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl","table",8),11,8),"[^\d\.]",""))`

Comment: thanks, your method and the other commenters worked great, but i ran into a problem. the method works great for normal numbers like 1234. but what i am currently importing is the earnings of a company(apple). and when i import it, it shows *76.31b*. and when i try the regaxreplace on it. it says value parameter 76.31b can not be parsed to a number. 

is there a way to fix this or potentially remove the "b" while still removing the **? thanks for all the help btw

Comment: See the added formula at the bottom of my post above. If this meets the need, please mark the post as "Best Answer," which will let the community know that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding your function with REGEXREPLACE()

```
=REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl","table",8),11,8), "[*]","")
```